# How to summarise in dplyr on one column without specifying the column every time

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to `summarise` in `dplyr` (or with other code) on the same column without having to specify the column each time like this?

```
 summarise(temp1, earliest=min(ArrDelay), average= mean(ArrDelay), latest=(ArrDelay))
```

Comment: You could use `summarise_each` instead - like `summarise_each(temp1, funs(earliest = min, average = mean, latest = max), ArrDelay)`.

Comment: It might interest you that `summary(iris$Sepal.Length)` is a thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `summarise_each`, which can take a `funs` argument:

```
summarise_each(iris, funs(earliest = min, average = mean, latest = max), Sepal.Length)
#
#   earliest  average latest
# 1      4.3 5.843333    7.9
```